# Not able to pass JSON as HTTP parameter

Tags: java, json

I am using an open source REST API client program to do a web service call with POST method to my application inside my remote server and it's successfully done,the JSON string able to pass it to the server, all the required informations were updated and this is the trace from the open source program.

```
  POST /api/v1.4/loginRestrictionPolicies/blocked/rules HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.0.127:444
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
> User-Agent: insomnia/5.2.0
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 131
**| {
|   "description": "mm",
|   "name": "nn",
|   "enabled": "true",
|   "type": "ALLOW",
|   "clientAddress": "hug",
|   "expression": "mmam" 
| }**
* upload completely sent off: 131 out of 131 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: 
< Location: https://192.168.0.127:444/api/v1.4/loginRestrictionPolicies/blocked/rules/nn
< X-Login-Restriction-Policy-Name: blocked
< X-Login-Restriction-Rule-Name: nn
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 13 Jun 2017 06:58:05 GMT
```

But when i try to use my program to do the same way and there was no any update being done in the application stated in my remote server, my program didnt show any error message on it,so i have no clue on where i need to troubleshoot it because there is no any exception throw by the program. 
The JSON data will look like this

```
{
"description": "mm",
 "name": "nn",
 "enabled": "true",
 "type": "ALLOW",
 "clientAddress": "hug",
 "expression": "mmam" 
}
```

I also need to submit the password into the POST request for the web service call. This is my source code for the web service call and i am using Httpclient 4.5.2

```
public static void PostCall(String t,String rule1)
{
    int TIME_OUT = 1000;
    try 
    {
      System.out.println("in the PostCall method now :" +t);
      JSONObject jo1 = new JSONObject();
      jo1.put("name",rule1);
      jo1.put("enabled","true");
      jo1.put("type","DENY");
      jo1.put("clientAddress",t);
      jo1.put("expression","This IP violated the rule");
      jo1.put("description","You are in my list");  

      System.out.println("The JSON will look like :" +jo1.toString());    
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/security/cacerts");   
      SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null,new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
      SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext,new String[] { "TLSv1.2" }, null, new oopHostnameVerifier());

      HttpClient client1 = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://192.168.0.127:444/api/v1.4/loginRestrictionPolicies/blocked/rules");
      RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig
          .custom()
          .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.DEFAULT)
          .setExpectContinueEnabled(true)
          .setTargetPreferredAuthSchemes(Arrays.asList(AuthSchemes.NTLM, AuthSchemes.DIGEST))
          .setProxyPreferredAuthSchemes(Arrays.asList(AuthSchemes.BASIC)).build();

      RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.copy(defaultRequestConfig)
        .setSocketTimeout(TIME_OUT).setConnectTimeout(TIME_OUT)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(TIME_OUT).build();

      httpPost.setConfig(requestConfig);
      StringEntity entity1 = new StringEntity(jo1.toString());
      httpPost.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
      httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
      String cre1  = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("admin:admin").getBytes());
      httpPost.addHeader("Authorization","Basic" +cre1);
      httpPost.setEntity(entity1);
      HttpResponse res1 = client1.execute(httpPost);
      BufferedReader rd1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res1.getEntity().getContent()));
      String statusCode = null;

      while((statusCode=rd1.readLine())!=null)
      {
        if(statusCode == "201")
        {
              System.out.println("The IP is in the list now");
        }
      } 

    }
    catch(JSONException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you add else statement and print status ?if(statusCode == "201")
                  {
                     System.out.println("The IP is in the list now");
                  }

Comment: Did you really intend to post the login credentials? It seems to be a test server, but still ...

Comment: @Henry it's in my testing vmware, so doesn't really matter for the password